# Save form data(text field) in database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- I have created a user controller with login and logout.
- After login user should be able to give some comment in text box input and it should be saved in db.

How to associate the comment to the user. My users controller is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
     if user.save
       session[:user_id] = user.id
       redirect_to '/url'
     else
       redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end 

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

my urls controller is

```
class UrlsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    url = Url.new(url_params)
    url.save
    redirect_to @url
  end    

  def url_params
    params.require(:url).permit(:url)
  end

end
```

I am getting error in `url_params`. How it should be for a text field?

Comment: can you share the view code as well?

Comment: <h1>Enter your URL</h1>

<%= form_for :url, url: '/url' do |f| %>

  Title: <%= text_field_tag :url %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>

<% end %>

Comment: why do you want to save url?

Answer (score 0):

For example you need to create Comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

and create CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user

  def create
    @user.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried it. I shows undefined method comments for user. (No method error)

Comment: Did you create model Comment?

Comment: Yes. I have used UrlsController and model url.

Comment: class UrlsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_user

  def create
    @user.urls.create(url_params)
    redirect_to '/url'
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def url_params
   params.require(:url).permit(:text)
  end
end

Comment: class Url < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
end

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is, please?